# AWS Mobile Custom SignIn

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've already created a custom signin that works well with Google Firebase, but the app will need to be used in China, so Google is a no go. I've read through the AWS Cognito documentation but there doesn't seem to be a way to have authentication similar to Firebase where I can use a custom signin UI.

It just needs to be a simple sign in with an email and password, with no sign up feature. Is this possible to do with AWS Cognitio for Android?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AWS SDK for Android - Cognito Identity Provider to add SignIn feature to your app.

Import the following dependency to build.gradle file and perform gradle sync:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.6.25'
```

SignIn API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-user-sign-in-android

Add the following code in your app:

```
// Callback handler for the sign-in process 
AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() { 

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession) { 
        // Sign-in was successful, cognitoUserSession will contain tokens for the user   
    }

    @Override
    public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String userId) { 
        // The API needs user sign-in credentials to continue
        AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(userId, password, null);

        // Pass the user sign-in credentials to the continuation
        authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);

        // Allow the sign-in to continue
        authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation) { 
        // Multi-factor authentication is required; get the verification code from user
        multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation.setMfaCode(mfaVerificationCode);
        // Allow the sign-in process to continue
        multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation.continueTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
        // Sign-in failed, check exception for the cause
    } 
};

// Sign in the user 
cognitoUser.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
```

You can take a look at the sample app: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where exactly would I add this to my login activity?

Comment: You can take a look at the sample app to see how to use the API: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo. Yes, you can add it to the onCreate of your activity.